# How to update data without deleting anything else?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to set a value on my Firebase realtime-database.

Here is my database organization:

```
Users:
       U20180422:
                  ID: U20180422
                  Name: "Jason"
                  Surname: "Smith" 
                  Address: "4198 Norma Avenue"
                  Age: "30"
                  creation date: "04/22/2018"
       U20180311: ...
       U20180304: ...
       U20180215: ...
       ...
```

I make this snippet for write and it works:

```
<script language="javascript">
//this retrieves from the form of registration the ID of the user
var userId = document.getElementById("searchfield").value;

// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    //my configurations
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  console.log(firebase);

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('Users/' + userId);

var data = {
Account_validated = "OK"
}
ref.set(data)
</script>
```

But in this way the data that were present are deleted and only account_validated state is present in the path. So I thought I had to first retrieve all the data already in possession and then send them to the database along with the new data.

This is what is not working in my code:

```
    //Retrieve from database
        ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

 function gotData(data) {
    var value = data.val();
    var getvalue = Object.value(value);
    for (var i=0; i < value.lenght; i++) {
    var k = value[i];
    var name= value[k].Name;
    var surname= value[k].Surname;
    var address= value[k].Address;
    var age= value[k].Age;
    var creation_account_date= value[k].creation date;
    console.log(name, surname, address, age, creation date);
    }
 }

 function errData(err) {
    console.log('Error!');
    console.log(err);
 }

 {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        var childData = child.val();
        var name=child.val().Name;
        var surname=child.val().Surname;
        var address=child.val().Address;
        var age=child.val().Age;
        var creation_account_date=child.val().creation date
    });
});


   //Write
   var data = {
        ID: userId,
        Name: name,
        Surname: surname,
        Address: address,
        Age: age,
        creation date: creation_account_date
        }
   ref.set(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update only the keys that you specify in your data, use `update`:

```
var data = {
  Account_validated: "OK"
}
ref.update(data)
```

This will update only the `Account_validated` key under `ref`, and leave other child properties unmodified.

Comment: Thank you! you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you seeing?

At first glance you've got a typo in your for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i < value.lenght; i++)
```

You've misspelt length so `value.lenght` will resolve to `undefined` and execution will just skip over the loop.

Comment: Hello Batters, thanks so much for the support. In this situation my database don't receive more updates.